# How to add class to every 3rd element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I checked other posts and found this:

```
$('ul.landingpageboxes li:nth-child(1n+4)').addClass('noleftspace');
```

Does anyone know how to alter it so that I can add a class to every third list item?

Comment: Update 1n+4 with 3n - for reference - https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 2):

Use `(3n)` selector

```
$('ul.landingpageboxes li:nth-child(3n)').addClass('noleftspace');
```

This will select every 3rd element.

How this works:

3 * 1 =   3

3 * 2 =     6

3 * 3 =      9

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ucb0bdmj/)

For this, you can also use CSS to add styles.

```
ul.landingpageboxes li:nth-child(3n) {
    color: red;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ucb0bdmj/1/)

Comment: @nettle If this answer has helped you to solve problem, you can accept it as answer